# drupal :how to pass current userid as argument

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

i need to display the contents added by that user...

i have designed a view to display the result.. but it displays the results of all users.....
i need to display the contents added by that user...

when i pass the argument of userid it works, but is there any dynamic way to do that....

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is a list of nodes by the current user, the easiest way is to use the User:Current filter. Just click the [+] next to 'Filters', choose 'User:Current' from the list, click the 'Add' button and set the filter to 'Yes'.

The argument-method as described by streetparade (using the 'User: Uid' argument) is useful if you want users to see the list of other users as well. Suppose that your view's url is www.example.com/my-content. If you add a user argument, user #3 could see what user #7 has posted on www.example.com/my-content/7. If you want that, use the argument. If you do not want that, use the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
<?php

global $user;
$userId = $user->uid;
?>
```

You can access all this way

[image: Drupal UserID]
<sub>(source: [chromaticsites.com](http://blog-media.chromaticsites.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/screen_6_arge_settings_2.png))</sub>

Comment: How is this different from using the "User id from logged in user" option?

Comment: Whenever possible, you should always avoid writing custom php code stored in the db, but should instead use the options provided by views like marcvangend describe.